# Resolve external $ref using swagger-parser API

Tags: java, reference, swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I'm trying to create   API resources containing External file reference in parameters and responses and try to get these references resolved using swagger. (Support importing OpenAPI definitions with external references).

For that, I am getting the YAML files as file archive and there will be a master main.YAML file and from that other files are referenced.

```
    OpenAPIV3Parser openAPIV3Parser = new OpenAPIV3Parser();
    ParseOptions options = new ParseOptions();
    options.setResolve(true);
    options.setFlatten(true);
    OpenAPI openAPI = openAPIV3Parser.read(extractedLocation + "/main.yaml", null, options);
    String openAPIContent = Yaml.mapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(openAPI);
    APIDefinitionValidationResponse  apiDefinitionValidationResponse  = new APIDefinitionValidationResponse (); 
    apiDefinitionValidationResponse = OASParserUtil.validateAPIDefinition(openAPIContent, returnContent);
```

I tried with this code snippet but the `apiDefinitionValidationResponse` is throwing an error when there is `$ref` in the YAML file. If there's no `$ref` then apiDefinitionValidationResponse is a success and api is created.

So i doubt there is a problem in giving the data to `OASParserUtil.validateAPIDefinition` method (`validateAPIDefinition` method has no issues and it has been validated and tested)

Could someone help me with this?

The generated YAML file has `extensions{}` lines all over it

Error messages in debug logs:

```
attribute info.license.extensions is unexpected
attribute info.extensions is unexpected
attribute components.schemas.ErrorListItem.extensions is unexpected
attribute components.schemas.MenuItem.extensions is unexpected
attribute components.schemas.Order.extensions is unexpected
```

Comment: Please provide the error message ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i can tell from the error message and your result yaml is, that the transformation step adds some `extensions: {}` lines into the final yaml.

Having an `extensions` attribute at those places it complains about is not allowed by the OpenAPI  specification.

Looks like your yaml serialization is to simple. Looking at the [SerializerUtils](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen/serializer/SerializerUtils.java) from the openapi-generator they have a bit more configuration.

The extra module takes care of serializing only the interesting part of the OpenAPI object.

Comment: That is an explicit observation. i'm asking why it happens and how to get rid of it ?